# Real-Time Slack clone with AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, authentication, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, slack

I tried to work this tutorial 
`https://thinkster.io/angularfire-slack-tutorial#authenticating-users-using-angularfire`

And the problem i have is with Firebase Authentication. In code there are no errors but it doesn't want to connect with base and error is:

```
Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from firebase.google.com/docs/auth/
```

I don't know what to do, if someone was playing with this and know the answer, please tell me, it bothering me last 3 days.

Comment: The message seems pretty simple, google wants you to update the authentication component of firebase.

Comment: Okey i know that, but how to do it. Documentation is to confused on firebase site. I just need to do that for this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you're following was written for Firebase 2.x. Projects created on firebase.google.com can only use the authentication of Firebase 3.x.

You will either have to find an updated tutorial (e.g. [this Firebase codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/)) or create a project on the [Firebase legacy console](https://www.firebase.com). That last option is only available if you created your account on that legacy console too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you solved this problem?

It's not too complicated, I am running the thinkster example with Firebase 3.x now.

Copy the web app config code from the firebase console somewhere in your code (I put it at the beginning of app.js):

```
var config = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxx",
  authDomain: "projectid.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://projectid.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "projectid.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var FirebaseUrl = firebase.database().ref();
```

Change all the ref variables to this format:

```
var channelMessagesRef = FirebaseUrl.child('channelMessages');
```

Replace the auth functions according to:

https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/migration/1XX-to-2XX.md

(also some "key()" has to be replaced with "key")

I think that's it. If you run into problems let me know.

Also another note:

The rules file is wrong, it gives read access to private messages to everybody. I changed it to this one:

```
"userMessages":{
  "$uid1":{
    ".read": "$uid1 === auth.uid",
    "$uid2":{
        ".read": "$uid2 === auth.uid",
      "$messageId":{
        ".read": "auth !== null && ($uid1 === auth.uid || $uid2 === auth.uid)",
        ".write": "auth !== null && newData.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",
        ".validate": "$uid1 < $uid2 && newData.child('timestamp').exists()",
        "body":{
          ".validate": "newData.exists() && newData.val().length > 0"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```